# Smart Commits for Jira and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I use jira with bitbucket, and I am confusing with when I should use smart commit. I work in my local repo, and I will push my codes to remote repo at the end of the day. Should I use smart commit for all my commits to push? Or only the merge commit after the pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use smart commit in all commits because this way there will be more accessible information about the issue worked in Jira. If you use smart commit only in the merge, the only thing that would happen is that the commit section would not appear in the Jira tasks.

[See this image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RTInIHSVABvZ0Gl0bueTWu22KwcDREmzE2Uw2g5vjCpUxFhQnZ6aXh5AR9RYtQIjbnESFP08uugQ4Dc6E1o38SbrLhAxKsD2aIZS6siJdgq0aCykWfF1dU3IfyWbsTu15tUmJQ1ARqPHfyu3zGLqwagKnq7QYH5heuomxg1CLtWESiz2TenGiV-sPryjPJo2ZlQFDhoSJ_7HcpOQ1ts5qFto754tP2APQbi0wtTPhzLdxfh47Q6DQaHsa936kOrNfT7lWQ8V3k0Ew1Q7kyE-3y7g3XeRaAHiESnVtQgM_nzIRcUVZeDXGF2hDOnANIGrR7H0OtOJYYNYl6t_Edu7U69k51X0zfuAgTcEerv5artfr4wkeMfydbWhGu3m2srcIAOc9g07bNKGaePgIigv8hNmF5QG0IMMfjagy96R7eIrkNv9sevV6KYx3HWjuNUljcZSTX-6yyKojIvrrNenFCxBNE0ZLATuebuHI9cvVaEgQR1_mu2J0LT9a4_JkyPuZdG8R6y1RNZzJRUWSAiM6TCcPy0NsBar-mq1ulrkzYTRZNkTiS52ydYTOZnouvNvdw8v03gtM-SJKKms7bso7SLk2ZqJRyqA7ZxzsDpU8usTKmSbFxFym19Us5ArATJw-_rby17Nplg3arK6LBCpznR3GHWLwmJlJvXfzjMJRqIkPjVrO6mG9tgZgwJmHg=w587-h188-no)